# awk warning on escape sequence

Tags: awk

I am firing an `awk` command with the character class ere.

```
cere='^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|\/\/)[[:space:]]*'
```

This gives the awk warning.

```
awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/'
```

Is this something to worry about or fix?

Here is the awk call I use for matching regions

```
charcl_ere='^[[:space:]]*([#;!]+|@c|\/\/)[[:space:]]*'

begrec="${charcl_ere}${selec}[[:space:]]*$"
endrec="${charcl_ere}# end of ${fieldval}[[:space:]]*$"

awk -v ccls="$charcl_ere" -v begrsc="$begrec" -v endrsc="$endrec" \
    '$0 ~ begrsc { insc=1; next }
     $0 ~ endrsc { insc=0; print "" }
     insc { sub(ccls,""); print }' "$efile"
```

Comment: Well, what is it supposed to match? `/` or `\/`?

Comment: I want to match C and C++ comments (`//`)

Comment: The forward slash itself is not a regular expression metacharacter - you only need to escape it in an awk [regexp constant](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Constant-Regexps), since that uses `/` as a delimiter (same reason as in sed). Since you are passing your expression in as a string variable, it becomes a [Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) and the escapes are redundant.

Comment: @steeldriver answer and you get an upvote

Comment: @Rinzwind busy rn - will check back later and post an answer if no-one else has done so in the meantime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The forward slash character `/` isn't special inside a regular expression. It needs to be escaped in an awk [regexp constant](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Using-Constant-Regexps) for the same reason that it needs to be escaped in a sed expression like `s/pattern/replacement/`<sup>1</sup>; that is, because `/` is being used to *delimit* the regexp. So given

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo//bar' 'foo\\baz'
foo//bar
foo\\baz
```

then

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo//bar' 'foo\\baz' | awk '$0 ~ /o\/\/b/'
foo//bar
```

However when you pass a regular expression to awk as a string, it becomes a [dynamic regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps). Because it is a *string expression* rather than a regexp constant, there is no delimiter conflict and `/` is unambiguously a literal character:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo//bar' 'foo\\baz' | awk -v re='o//b' '$0 ~ re'
foo//bar
```

**This** is the situation that gives rise to the warning that you are asking about i.e. if you (unnecessarily) escape the slashes, awk will remind you that *inside a string expression*, `\/` is the same as `/`:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo//bar' 'foo\\baz' | awk -v re='o\/\/b' '$0 ~ re'
awk: warning: escape sequence `\/' treated as plain `/'
foo//bar
```

---

Although you didn't ask about backslashes, it's probably worth mentioning those as well. They **are** special characters in regular expressions, and need to be escaped to make them literal in a regexp constant:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo//bar' 'foo\\baz' | awk '$0 ~ /o\\\\b/'
foo\\baz
```

This time however, because the escaping is not related to the delimiter, it's still required when using a dynamic regexp. To add to the confusion, `\` is also special in string expressions (`\t` represents a TAB character for example). So when using a dynamic regexp, each `\` needs to be escaped **twice** - once to make it a string literal, and once more to make the string literal a regexp literal:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo//bar' 'foo\\baz' | awk -v re='o\\\\\\\\b' '$0 ~ re'
foo\\baz
```

Finally, if you're using a recent version of GNU awk (aka gawk), then there is the possibility to use a [strongly typed regexp constant](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants), in which you *would* need to escape forward slashes even though you are passing a string from the shell:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'foo//bar' 'foo\\baz' | gawk -v re='@/o\/\/b/' '$0 ~ re'
foo//bar
```

---

<sup>1</sup> sed allows you to choose a different delimiter instead of escaping the default delimiter ex. `s:o//b::` or `\%o//%`; so far as I know, awk does not.